# Why doesn't Inkscape recognize the Ubuntu color palettes?

Tags: 11.10, inkscape

Inkscape 0.48.2 refuses to show my newly added Ubuntu color palettes in the color palettes selection menu.

I have downloaded the [Ubuntu color palettes](http://design.canonical.com/brand/Tools/colour_palettes/gimp_palettes.zip) for GIMP/InkScape from [design.canonical.com](http://design.canonical.com/), extracted the files and copied them to `/usr/share/inkscape/palettes/` where all the other color palettes are.

I've even made sure that all the files have the same permissions, just in case.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the color palettes were not saved correctly. I have re-saved them in a proper format and put them on Ubuntu One.

Here are the [files](http://ubuntuone.com/2Qzs497M4URoYGBr538bcz). In the archive there is now a readme file explaining the installation process as well.

**Update**

I've filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-branding/+bug/893049) against *ubuntu-branding* and sent a fix to be replaced with the currently available palette on [design.canonical.com](http://design.canonical.com).